Unable to install Nvidia drivers on MacBook Pro 2012 SSD, but it works on external flash drive
Introduction
I'm using my MacBook Pro Late 2012 for work in Python, game development in JavaScrip, 2D graphics creation, and just normal daily internet browsing.
Ever since I first installed Ubuntu on this computer, I have been having problems with NVIDIA driver installation.
Each time I tried, I always got a black screen without the possibility of entering the virtual terminal.
The Stick drive attempt
So I decided to install Ubuntu Studio 24.04 on a flash drive to see if I would manage to install these drivers here without any risk of losing my Ubuntu setup and skipping the frustration step.
Provisional victory
And actually, I managed to do so. I've got a Kubuntu with a working NVIDIA 470 driver. SuperTuxKart FPS increased from 20 to 122, and everything was great. Feeling victorious I formatted my SSD 22.04 Gnome Ubuntu to welcome 24.04 Ubuntu Studio on my work machine. I have created a snapshot of my terminal history and I followed the same steps on the fresh Ubuntu Studio (snapshot from my history at the end)
The SSD problem
Of course, after installing drivers, it failed to load. So I tried once again and once again.
After a few tries I started experimenting with different versions, options, and with Bumblebee but still got the same black screen.
I really don't know what to do to have these drivers installed and start using the computer with full GPU potential.
Path that led me to the success on the flash drive...
Please note that this is a snapshot of the whole history that led me to work Nvidia 470 drivers, it is a little messy
1  sudo apt-install neofetch
2  sudo apt install neofetch
3  neofetch
4  ls
5  ls -a
6  cd .config/
7  ls
8  nvim
# Here I added one extension to the taskbar multiple times and I didn't know how to delete it, lol
9  nano plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
10  sudo apt install neovim
11  nvim plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
12  plasmashell --replace
13  nvim plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
14  plasmashell --replace
15  jobs
16  kill %9
17  kill 1
18  sudo kill 1
19  jobs
20  sudo kill 1
21  jobs
22  fg
23  plasmashell --replace
24  jobs
25  fg
26  plasmashell --replace
27  jobs
28  kill %1
29  jobs
30  kill %1
31  jobs
32  reboot
33  neofetch
# start NVIDIA drivers installation
34  nvidia-settings # it's not installed here
35  sudo apt install nvidia-settings
36  nvidia-settings
37  hwinfo --gfxcard
38  sudo nvidia-xconfig # only the last usage of this command will do anything
39  sudo systemctl status gpu-manager
40  sudo nvidia-xconfig
41  sudo apt install nvidia-xconfig
42  reboot
43  nvidia-xconfig
44  neofetch
45  sudo apt install nvidia-utils-470
46  nvidia-xconfig
47  sudo nvidia-xcondig
48  sudo nvidia-xconfig # this is the first successful use of this command
49  reboot
50  gpustat
51  sudo apt install gpustat
52  gpustat
53  gpustat --debug
54  neofetch
55  sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
56  sudo apt install nvidia-drivers-470
57  sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470
58  reboot
59  gpustat  # everything works, SuperTuxCart has now 122 FPS, previousle i
60  history

Neofetch ran on stick drive
milessic@milessic-MacBookPro:~$ neofetch
           `.:/ossyyyysso/:.               milessic@milessic-MacBookPro 
        .:oyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyo:`           ---------------------------- 
      -oyyyyyyyodMMyyyyyyyysyyyyo-         OS: Kubuntu 24.04 LTS x86_64 
    -syyyyyyyyyydMMyoyyyydmMMyyyyys-       Host: MacBookPro10,1 1.0 
   oyyysdMysyyyydMMMMMMMMMMMMMyyyyyyyo     Kernel: 6.8.0-31-lowlatency 
 `oyyyydMMMMysyysoooooodMMMMyyyyyyyyyo`    Uptime: 7 mins 
 oyyyyyydMMMMyyyyyyyyyyyysdMMysssssyyyo    Packages: 3087 (dpkg), 11 (snap) 
-yyyyyyyydMysyyyyyyyyyyyyyysdMMMMMysyyy-   Shell: bash 5.2.21 
oyyyysoodMyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyydMMMMysyyyo   Resolution: 2880x1800 
yyysdMMMMMyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyysosyyyyyyyy   DE: Plasma 5.27.11 
yyysdMMMMMyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy   WM: KWin 
oyyyyysosdyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyydMMMMysyyyo   Theme: [Plasma], Materia [GTK2], Materia-dark [GTK3] 
-yyyyyyyydMysyyyyyyyyyyyyyysdMMMMMysyyy-   Icons: [Plasma], ubuntustudio-dark [GTK2/3] 
 oyyyyyydMMMysyyyyyyyyyyysdMMyoyyyoyyyo    Terminal: konsole 
 `oyyyydMMMysyyyoooooodMMMMyoyyyyyyyyo     CPU: Intel i7-3615QM (8) @ 3.300GHz 
   oyyysyyoyyyysdMMMMMMMMMMMyyyyyyyyo      GPU: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller 
    -syyyyyyyyydMMMysyyydMMMysyyyys-       GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M Mac Edition 
      -oyyyyyyydMMyyyyyyysosyyyyo-         Memory: 2338MiB / 15898MiB 
        ./oyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyo/.
           `.:/oosyyyysso/:.`                                      
                                                                   


Please help with my old friend, I don't want to replace it yet, it's been a very good computer for several years, but I need just a little more GPU power to fully use it.
